# Let's get critical: Dec 2013 Site Self-Evaluation

Tags: discussion, site-evaluation

We all love [Raspberry Pi Stack Exchange](http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com), but there is a whole world of people out there who need answers to their questions and don't even know that this site exists. When they arrive from Google, what will their first impression be? Let's try to look at this site through the eyes of someone who's never seen it before, and see how we stack up against the rest of the 'Net.

The [Site Self-Evaluation review queue](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/review/site-eval) is open and populated with 10 questions that were asked and answered in the last quarter. Run a few Google searches to see how easy they are to find and compare the answers we have with the information available on other sites.

Rating the questions is only a part of the puzzle, though. Do you see a pattern of questions that should have been closed but are not? Questions or answers that could use an edit? Anything that's going really well? **Post an answer below to share your thoughts** and discuss these questions and the site's health with your fellow users!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Final Results

- [Cross Compiling to Raspberry Pi from Windows with External Libraries](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/10311/cross-compiling-to-raspberry-pi-from-windows-with-external-libraries)

**Net Score: 5** (Excellent: 5, Satisfactory: 3, Needs Improvement: 0)

---

- [Raspberry Pi Reboot Cycle After SD Clone - Card works on old Pi but not new ones](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/10435/raspberry-pi-reboot-cycle-after-sd-clone-card-works-on-old-pi-but-not-new-ones)

**Net Score: 4** (Excellent: 4, Satisfactory: 6, Needs Improvement: 0)

---

- [Use raspi to redirect wireless/bluetooth keyboard to different computers](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/10436/use-raspi-to-redirect-wireless-bluetooth-keyboard-to-different-computers)

**Net Score: 3** (Excellent: 4, Satisfactory: 3, Needs Improvement: 1)

---

- [Can one mount an NFS directory at /](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/10302/can-one-mount-an-nfs-directory-at)

**Net Score: 3** (Excellent: 3, Satisfactory: 4, Needs Improvement: 0)

---

- [Error when running X apps with XWayland: "cannot open display: :0"](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/10206/error-when-running-x-apps-with-xwayland-cannot-open-display-0)

**Net Score: 1** (Excellent: 1, Satisfactory: 7, Needs Improvement: 0)

---

- [Save output files and store them as a dd-mm-yyy hh-mm format](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/11739/save-output-files-and-store-them-as-a-dd-mm-yyy-hh-mm-format)

**Net Score: 0** (Excellent: 2, Satisfactory: 4, Needs Improvement: 2)

---

- [How to connect 20 DS18B20 temperature sensors to RPi?](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/11661/how-to-connect-20-ds18b20-temperature-sensors-to-rpi)

**Net Score: -1** (Excellent: 2, Satisfactory: 3, Needs Improvement: 3)

---

- [How do I boot directly to a VNC or RDP session on a Raspberry Pi?](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/10594/how-do-i-boot-directly-to-a-vnc-or-rdp-session-on-a-raspberry-pi)

**Net Score: -1** (Excellent: 1, Satisfactory: 4, Needs Improvement: 2)

---

- [Raspberry Pi RasPiComm](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/10389/raspberry-pi-raspicomm)

**Net Score: -2** (Excellent: 2, Satisfactory: 2, Needs Improvement: 4)

---

- [I need help setting up a Raspberry dash cam](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/10512/i-need-help-setting-up-a-raspberry-dash-cam)

**Net Score: -4** (Excellent: 0, Satisfactory: 2, Needs Improvement: 4)

---